# Craft with ElasticSearch as a backend

Tags: craft-pro

Hope this kind of question (a pointer request, actually) is alright with StackExchange guidelines. We're looking to store all our data in ES. Is this possible at the moment? Any plugin to do so? We're happy to explore Enterprise pricing if needed.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking if you can replace the control panel search logic with ES or search logic on the front-end or both?

Comment: If someone could extend a bit on how using elasticsearch would work on the frontend side of things, I'd be interested in that

Comment: @BradBell, we want ES to be the entire database. No MySQL or PG. Just ES.

Comment: @KhomNazid ElasticSearch isn't a relational database, so no.  Craft 2 only supports MySQL and Craft 3 supports MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

Although not related specifically to Craft, we built https://www.jelliscraig.com.au website using CraftCMS with all property listing data is stored in ElasticSearch. We use a simple plugin for the ElasticSearch PHP client but the integration is front-end only, for the most part. 
We have been testing pushing Craft generated content into ElasticSearch via the element API and in theory its a workable solution however for our specific situation we see no huge benefit in storing all general content externally.

Comment: Can you give some pointers a to how you integrated elsasitcsearch with the craft search? Or what plugin you used? That would be much appreciated.

Comment: Elastic search is not integrated into the craft search . We have a small plug-in which queries elasticsearch and the craft database and merges results to display on the front end auto suggest field.   This simple set up is fine for our use case because the property listing data stored in elasticsearch is managed by an external application.   If you have any specific questions I'll be happy to share ideas or code with you.